# cakephp writing SQL statement

Tags: sql, cakephp

i am having trouble with cakephp and writing an sql query, I have the sql code written out but am not sure on how to code it in cake.

```
`users`          - id, name, address
`accounts`       - id, companyname, abn
`accounts_users` - id, account_id, user_id
`templates`      - id, name, description, account_id
`fields`         - id, name, description, template_id
```

- users habtm accounts
- accounts habtm users
- accounts hasMany templates
- templates belongsTo accounts
- templates hasMany fields
- fields belongsTo templates

**what I am trying to get my find statement in the fieldscontroller, to add the template_id field is to do is this**

```
select t.id
from  template.t, account_users.au, user.u
where t.account_id=au.account_id AND
au.user_id=users.id;
```

this is the code I have so far in my fields in controller:

```
function add() {
    $this->Session->setFlash("Please create your required fields.");
    $templates = $this->Template->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('id'),
        'conditions' => array('id'=> $this->Auth->user('id'))));
    $this->set('templates','$templates');

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Field->create(); 

        if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) {     
            if ($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'controller' => 'fields',
                    'action' => 'add'));
            } 
            if ($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
        }
    }
}
```

the sql statement it currently is printing out is

```
SELECT `Template`.`id` FROM `pra`.`templates` AS `Template` WHERE `id` = 14
```

`id` is referring to the `users` table id

**The error is i am trying to get the template_id in the the add form. the find function isn't getting the template_id's, it is instead grabbing the user - id**

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: i am trying to get the template_id in the the add form. the find function isn't getting the template_id's

Comment: `template_id` on the basis of what??

Comment: template_id from the templates table. 

im assuming the user - id from session data queries the accounts_users table, which then checks the account_ids against the user_id then account_id is in the template table which pulls the template - id, i did it very similar with inserting the account_id in the template table

Comment: This link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with your field names. Are they in line with the code/name conventions?
Please post the table layout of the models.

if template_id is the primary key for the table templates you should use:

```
public $primaryKey = 'template_id';
```

in your templates model.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey

and offcourse your getting what your asking. The query should be more like:

```
$templates = $this->Template->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Template.template_id'),
    'conditions' => array('User.id'=> $this->Auth->user('id'))));
```

But that is dificult to say without your exact table layout.